# Core Data one-to-one relationship does not work properly

Tags: core-data, relationship, nsfetchrequest, one-to-one

```
// Test listing all words with their sentence
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Word"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
[fetchRequest setFetchLimit:10];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

 for (Word *info in fetchedObjects) {
     NSLog(@"Word object: %@", info.word);
     Sentence *details = info.relatedToSentence;
     NSLog(@"Sentence object: %@", details.sentence);
 }
```

I have two entities called Word and Sentence. In each entity there is an attribute called word and sentence, respectively. The relationship is inverse, not optional, and one-to-one.

I am able to extract records from both entities separately, but somehow I can't fetch related objects through one entity, what did I do wrong?
The code above works, it is printing out value only for word objects and (null) for sentence objects... I am using sqlite as source for this database. I filled the sqlite file which is created by Xcode after modeling up my model.

Comment: The code looks OK. If `info.relatedToSentence` prints as (null) then then the Word object is not related to a Sentence object. How did you fill the sqlite file?

Comment: @martin Yeah, how should I set up the relationship? I fill it by inserting a string value in zword and zsentence in their table, i.e. two separate tables called ZWORD and ZSENTENCE.

Comment: Why don't you use Core Data to fill the initial database? Write a small command line tool that creates the data base and creates the managed objects and relationships. Modifying the sqlite file directly is not recommended and error-prone. - (In your case ZSENTENCE would have a ZRELATEDTOWORD column and ZWORD would have a ZRELATEDTOSENTENCE column, and both have to be filled correctly.)

Comment: @martin Because it is a huge database, so I have to prefill it. I'm testing with 5 values now, but it is still not working. Really? I see ZRELATEDTOWORD and ZRELATEDTOSENTENCE in the sqlite, yes, what should I fill them with?

Comment: What I meant is that you write a *separate* tool that runs only once to create the database and then copy the database as a resource into your real project. - (ZRELATEDTOWORD would be the Z_PK of the related word and ZRELATEDTOSENTENCE the Z_PK of the related sentence.)

Comment: @martin Ah, I see, but isn't it slower than prefilling with bash script? Ah, the key is to have unique number in primary key and relationship key numbers. Now it is working perfectly, thank you :-D!!! ps. please write your answer in own post, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your Core Data model the SQLite tables would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ZSENTENCE ( Z_PK INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Z_ENT INTEGER, Z_OPT INTEGER, ZRELATEDTOWORD INTEGER, ZSENTENCE VARCHAR );
CREATE TABLE ZWORD ( Z_PK INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Z_ENT INTEGER, Z_OPT INTEGER, ZRELATEDTOSENTENCE INTEGER, ZWORD VARCHAR );
```

where ZRELATEDTOWORD is the primary key (Z_PK) of the related word, and ZRELATEDTOSENTENCE
the primary key of the related sentence. Both have to be filled correctly.

***BUT:*** Please note that modifying the Core Data SQLite file is not recommended and
error-prone. The format is not documented officially and *might* change in the future.

I still recommend to write a separate command-line tool (which can use the same Core Data
model as your main project) that uses Core Data methods to create and fill the
initial database.

Comment: Thank you. A separate tool app for prefilling is a good idea!